# Import TypeScript interfaces in SvelteKit?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a starting SvelteKit project. I am trying to reuse an interface in multiple places.

The file is placed in `/src/lib/choice.ts`.

```
export interface Choice {
    id: number;
    value: string;
}
```

However, when I try to reference this interface in a Svelte component like so:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import {Choice} from "$lib/choice";
</script>
```

I get this error:

```
500
The requested module '/src/lib/choice.ts' does not provide an export named 'Choice'
SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/lib/choice.ts' does not provide an export named 'Choice'
```

My IDE, however, thinks this is perfectly valid, up to and including allowing click-navigation to the Choice declaration.

If, however, I change the declaration to this:

```
export class Choice {
    id!: number;
    value!: string;
}
```

Everything works and my IDE is happy.

What's going on here? I don't understand why the interface doesn't work but the class declaration does.

Comment: thanks so much for asking this question - I could not understand what was happening and it took a lot of googling to find this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have to annotate this as a type import:

```js
import type { Choice } from "$lib/choice";
```

If you look at the [default `tsconfig.json` for SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#generated-types-default-tsconfig-json), there is an explanation:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // this ensures that types are explicitly
    // imported with `import type`, which is
    // necessary as svelte-preprocess cannot
    // otherwise compile components correctly
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
```

Comment: That was it, adding type allowed it to work.

I've accepted the answer, but is there a bit more explanation? Is this because interfaces just "vanish" when compiled to JS by TypeScript, or is there something else going on...?

Comment: @WillIverson It is because of components being processed in isolation. See [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/issues/318).

Comment: Very interesting. I can tell I'm getting better at TypeScript as I can follow [most] of that thread. ;) Thanks!